# Does standard mandates that stream-constructors don't access stream buffer?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

[This](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/39-3.html) (pretty old) article on iostreams and streambuf argues, that the following code is OK:

```
class DerivedStreamBuf : public std::streambuf {
  // ...
};

class DerivedOutputStream : public std::ostream {
  public:
    DerivedOutputStream():
      std::ios(0), std::ostream(&dsb) {}        //1
    // ...
  private:
    DerivedStreamBuf dsb;
    // ...
};
```

It might be problematic, because when `ostream` is constructed `dsb` isn't yet initialized and thus UB could be the effect. For the destructor it might be the other way around: `dsb` is already destructed and could be used in the destructor of `ostream`.

However, the article argues, "the C++ standard mandates that no parent class constructors or destructors (ios, istream, or ostream) access the stream buffer".

While the case of destructor is straight forward, e.g. for [`~ostream`](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.cons#4):

> virtual ~basic_ostream();
> Remarks: Does not perform any operations on rdbuf().

It is less clear for [constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.cons#1):

> explicit basic_ostream(basic_streambuf<charT, traits>* sb); Effects:
> Initializes the base class subobject with basic_­ios<charT,
> traits>​::​init(sb) ([basic.ios.cons]).

Does it means this is the only possible effect, does this standard-formulation not allow for other effects, which are implementation details of `std::ostream` and could potentially access non-initialized `dsb`?

My question: Does that standard guarantees, that the above code is portable, i.e. works for all standard-compliant implementations of `std::ostream`?

Answer (score 2):

> Does that standard guarantees, that the above code is portable, i.e. works for all standard-compliant implementations of `std::ostream`?

Yes.

At the point of calling `std::ostream(&dsb)` the `dsb` member of `DerivedOutputStream` has been *allocated* but not *initialized*. Meaning, we may take its address by we may not yet read its (uninitialized) value.

As linked in the question, the [[ostream.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.cons) specifies the constructors of `std::basic_ostream`, and, particularly, the one chosen in you example is [[ostream.cons]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.cons#1)

> explicit basic_ostream(basic_streambuf<charT, traits>* sb);
>
> **Effects:** Initializes the base class subobject with `basic_­ios<charT, traits>​::​init(sb)` ([basic.ios.cons]).
>
> **Postconditions:** `rdbuf() == sb`.

[[tab:basic.ios.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:basic.ios.cons) describe the effects of invoking `void init(basic_streambuf<charT, traits>* sb)`, one which is particularly the post-condition described in the constructor above:

> ```
> rdbuf() == sb
> ```

and the rest of which does performs no read access to the underlying buffer to which `sb` points.

Now, `rdbuf()` is just a pointer, so this means the `sb` pointer passed to init *by value* (the pointer, that is) will be use to initialize `rdbuf()`. However, there is no side effect of reading the underlying buffer that `sb` points to, at this point.

> [...] not allow for other effects, ...?

Indeed, an implementation for, particularly, the `void init(basic_streambuf<charT, traits>*)` function need to respect and not expand the well-specified effects of [[tab:basic.ios.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:basic.ios.cons).

---

> This (**pretty old**) article ...

Note that the state of [ostream.cons] has been basically unchanged since the dawn of C++ time; we may e.g. have a look at [[lib.input.output]](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/html/sep94/lib-iostreams.html) from [the September 1994 C++ Working Paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/html/sep94/)

> 27.2.4.1.1  basic_ostream constructor      [lib.basic.ostream.sb.cons]
>
> ```
> basic_ostream(basic_streambuf<charT,baggage>* sb);
> ```
>
> 1 Constructs  an object of class basic_ostream, assigning initial values to the base class by calling `basic_ios<charT,baggage>::init(sb)`.

and

> **27.1.3.1.34  basic_ios::init [lib.basic.ios::init]**
>
> ```
> void init(basic_streambuf<charT,baggage>* sb_arg);
> ```
>
> 1 The postconditions of this function are indicated in Table 8:
>
> ```
>                       Table 8--init effects
>
>                +----------------------------------+
>                |Element            Value          |
>                +----------------------------------+
>                |sb        sb_arg                  |
>                |tiestr    a null pointer          |
>                |state     goodbit  if  sb_arg  is |
>                |          not   a  null  pointer, |
>                |          otherwise badbit.       |
>                |except    goodbit                 |
>                |fmtfl     skipws | dec            |
>                |wide      zero                    |
>                |prec      6                       |
>                |fillch    the space character     |
>                |loc       new   locale(),   which |
>                |          means the default value |
>                |          is the  current  global |
>                |          locale;9)               |
>                |iarray    a null pointer          |
>                |parray    a null pointer          |
>                +----------------------------------+
> ```

which describe the same delegation via an `init()` call with well-defined effects.

Comment: The crucial point of your answer is, that “Effects” in standard means that only these effects are allowed. Could you provide a source for that? E.g. calling a parent-constructor could also be an effect. Is parent constructor not called?

Comment: @ead my interpretations of the library specification has always been that effects accurately describe actions by a given function, and that any preconditions are specifically stated (e.g. whether input iterators or pointers need to be _dereferenceable_). See [general structure description](http://eel.is/c++draft/description#structure.specifications-3.3) as well as the spec for [alg.swap](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.swap#6) where an input iterator is explicitly required to be dereferenceble as a precondition to the function (less UB will occur).

Comment: I would assume, that it is an implicit requirement to pass a pointer to a valid object. For example `ifstream(const char* s, ...);` doesn't explicitly specify that `s` must be a pointer to a valid c-string (http://eel.is/c++draft/ifstream#cons-2), however passing a pointer to some (uninitialized) memory is an UB.

Comment: Also "Effects" surely don't describe all possible effects. For example, in some (most?) implementations constructor of `basic_ostream` would also initialize the member variable where the result of `gcount` is stored to 0, however this is an implementation detail, which is not mentioned under "Effects" in standard. So I'm not sure it is possible to follow, that standard gives there any guarantees.